# Return a list of lists to template and render it

Tags: django, list, templates, django-templates, django-views

In my project I deal with various sorts of events taking places in different cities. I'd like to present list of events per city in a template, but how to do that ? My view now looks like this :

```
def events_by_state(request, state):
    cities = City.objects.filter(state_slug=state)
```

For each city I'd like do a query :

```
for c in cities:
    events_list = Event.objects.filter(city=c)
```

But then I have problem in what form and how should I send it, as well as use in my template ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you do that? Just access the reverse attribute Django creates.

```
{% for city in cities %}
  {% for event in city.event_set.all %}
 ....
```

Comment: I can use that in template ? damn I didn't know that. Works in 1.1 also ?

Comment: @ignacioVazquez-Abrams, great thing!! thanks, this helped me now like a drop of water in dessert.